# Remove Â from output besides copyright symbol

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
<h5 align="center" padding="5">Example © 2016</h5>
```

The output of this line in code contains a letter A with ^ on the top. I want the output to be like this only

Example © 2016

and not this:

Example Â© 2016

Comment: It may just be an encoding or hidden character issue. You can try `&#169;` instead of the copyright symbol and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try using `&copy;` instead. My bet is you saved it as windows-1252 or some other encoding and are outputting it as UTF-8